# Windows Embedded Compact 7 service and Thread Local Storage

Tags: windows-services, windows-ce, thread-local-storage

I develop a Windows Embedded Compact 7 (aka Windows Embedded CE 7) service. The [Boost.Log library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial.html) is used for logging, which in case uses the [Boost Thread library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread.html). Trying to add a log entry from the **[xxx_IOControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee499501.aspx)** service method crashes.

After some investigation I have found, that the reason for the crash is dereferencing a NULL pointer in the add_thread_exit_function in the thread.cpp Boost Thread source file. The initial reason for the NULL pointer itself, is the possibly incorrect behavior of the **[TlsGetValue/TlsSetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488590.aspx)** Windows API functions. Specifically, in the following code:

```
BOOL setOk = TlsSetValue(tlsKey, originalData);
LPVOID returnedData = TlsGetValue(tlsKey);
```

being called within the xxx_IOControl call, **returnedData is NULL, while originalData is not NULL**; setOk is TRUE, GetLastError() being called after both TlsXXX functions returns ERROR_SUCCESS.
While in the same code being called within the **[xxx_Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee499774.aspx)** call, returnedData is returned correctly equal to the originalData value. In both calls (xxx_Init and xxx_IOControl) the same tlsKey is used and there is no [TlsFree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488903.aspx) calls between them.

Also, there is one more fact that is probably related. [DllMain(DLL_THREAD_ATTACH)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488450.aspx) is not called for the thread calling the xxx_IOControl - both in my service DLL and boost_thread.dll.

Is there some special thread machinery for Windows CE services? Does anybody have any related information that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, Windows CE services are managed as drivers, user mode drivers in CE 6 and later. 
The calling thread "migrates" in the context of a different process (nk for kernel mode drivers, services for services) and can access its address space for the time of the call (something that is usually not possible when you are running inside a regular process). Migration is different from thread creation, that's why DllMain is not called when a thread migrates into your own process address space. 
GetDirectCallerProcessId() will return the process-id of the caller (in any XXX_* fnction, not just inside XXX_IoControl), but will not help much with the TLS issue you experience. An alternative approach would be using a dictionary to store the information you currently associate to a thread using TLS. You get no notification when a thread is closed in another process so you'll not know when you could release data for a specific thread, but you may overcome this by using processid+threadid as the key and removing from your internal dictionary all the keys related to a specific process when your XXX_Close entry point is called (if a process closes the handle it will no longer be able to call ioctls and when a process terminates is granted that its handles will be closed and so your XXX_close function is called once). If you have a process calling your service from different threads without closing the handle in between that may be an issue and generate some memory leak on the system. You may also periodically check if threads are still running using the toolhelp library functions and remove non valid ids and create a new context for a thread as soon as you get a call from it.

Answer (score 0):

More investigation's done. Seems like Windows CE 7 services's xxx_IOControl (and some other) function is called in some special way, specifically, in a **thread of a different process**, not the servicesd.exe process, which initially loads and calls the xxx_Init function.

This can be proved by comparing the returned values of [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488631.aspx)() and [GetProcessIdOfThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683216(v=vs.85).aspx)([GetCurrentThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488202.aspx)()). The former always returns an ID of the servicesd.exe process, while the latter returns the same ID in xxx_Init function, but different ID in xxx_IOControl function.

The same fact can also be checked by enumerating running threads by the ToolHelp API. Within the xxx_Init call both **th32OwnerProcessID** and **th32CurrentProcessID** members of the [THREADENTRY32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488795.aspx) structure have the same value for the current thread, while **within the xxx_IOControl the th32OwnerProcessID for the current thread is different**.

At the end, the TlsSetValue/TlsGetValue functions within the xxx_IOControl are called with a TLS key, created for different process, and thus silently fail. [Since](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488159.aspx)

> TLS indexes are not valid across process boundaries. A DLL cannot
>   assume that an index assigned in one process is valid in another
>   process.

**Update:**
Based on the [Valter Minute answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25285611/23715) I've ended up implementing the Windows TlsXXX API myself. Basically, I've created corresponding functions in Boost Thread library, which implements the Thread Local Storage functionality in terms of a dictionary, that holds thread local data using TLS index, owner process id and thread id as keys. And then I changed all calls to TlsXXX Windows API to these new functions. Thread Local Storage API is used in Thread, Log and Asio libraries. Currently in my implementation a thread local data is freed only in case the TLS free function is called explicitly. No disposal is made in case the thread is detached. This is OK for my case, where the API is used from a couple of permanently running threads.